# Resize height and width equal with a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a `flexbox` where the `height` and the `width` reseizes are equal.
At the moment if I resize the window, just the width of the boxes resizes but is it possible to resize the `height` and the `width` equally?

I've created a Fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gamernamer/s6ujvbcg)

```css
.wrappie{
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 0;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    margin:-10px 0 0 -10px;
}
.forum_content {
    display: inline-block;
    background:grey;
    margin:10px 0 0 10px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height:250px; 
    max-width: 100%;
    width: calc(100% * (1/3) - 10px - 1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrappie">
  <div class="forum_content"></div>
  <div class="forum_content"></div>
  <div class="forum_content"></div>
  <div class="forum_content"></div>
</div>
```